# Relevance Vector Machine

Tags: python, machine-learning, computer-vision, bioinformatics

I am looking for a descent implementation of Relevance Vector Machines.

Can anyone recommend an python library or C++ implementation that I could interface?

Thanks heaps in advance,
EL

Comment: They are patented by Microsoft

Comment: python implementation: https://github.com/JamesRitchie/scikit-rvm

Answer (score 10):

In C++ you have these two libraries:

- [The Kernel-Machine Library](http://www.terborg.net/research/kml/reference/rvm.html)
- [dLib](http://dlib.net/ml.html#rvm_trainer)

Both have implementations of **RMV**. In Python, [scikit-learn](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/1513) seems it has plans to release it in the future.

[Matlab](http://www.vectoranomaly.com/downloads/downloads.htm) has also an implementation of RMV

Comment: Thanks, I'll check the libraries.

Comment: Patent has expired now and it looks like scikit-learn is still lacking an implementation.